# Is there a possibility to split a cell data to multiple columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, split

I have a clob column in a table whose data look like this

```
Name: ABC
Place: XYZ
Age: 123
Role: Developer
Skill: SQL
```

There are hundreds of records in table emp, where each emp_id will have a column wit description like above.
Now I want to display this data as each column for an emp id.
Something like this

`select emp_id, name, place, age, role, skill from emp where emp_id=xx;`

Is this possible to do using reg exp? or any other way? Please suggest.

Comment: Ummm ... not very clear. Is that CLOB column in the same EMP table you mentioned? Where is EMP_ID in that CLOB column (so that you could *join* it with the rest of data)? Could you explain it, maybe even posting some more sample data which would illustrate the problem?

Comment: It would be a **lot** easier if you stored that as a JSON value. The you can easily extract the values using Oracle JSON functions

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use REGEXP_SUBSTR on a CLOB column:

```
OPS$ORACLE@FTEX>desc emp;
 Name                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
 EMP_ID                                                                     NUMBER
 X                                                                          CLOB

OPS$ORACLE@FTEX>select * from emp;

    EMP_ID X
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Name: ABC Place: XYZ Age: 123 Role: Developer Skill: SQL

OPS$ORACLE@FTEX>create or replace view v_emp as
  2  (
  3  select emp_id,
  4         regexp_substr(x, '(\S*)(\:)(\s)(\S*)', 1, 1, null, 4) as Name,
  5         regexp_substr(x, '(\S*)(\:)(\s)(\S*)', 1, 2, null, 4) as Place,
  6         regexp_substr(x, '(\S*)(\:)(\s)(\S*)', 1, 3, null, 4) as Age,
  7         regexp_substr(x, '(\S*)(\:)(\s)(\S*)', 1, 4, null, 4) as Role,
  8         regexp_substr(x, '(\S*)(\:)(\s)(\S*)', 1, 5, null, 4) as Skill
  9         from emp
 10  );

View created.

OPS$ORACLE@FTEX>select * from v_emp;

    EMP_ID NAME                 PLACE                AGE   ROLE                 SKILL
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----- -------------------- --------------------
         1 ABC                  XYZ                  123   Developer            SQL

OPS$ORACLE@FTEX>
```